# magento encryption and decryption

Tags: magento, encryption, passwords, http-headers

How to use password encryption function of magento at the time of login in admin panel using java-script so that nobody can see the real password in HTTP headers of different browser?

Comment: Use HTTPS. Everything else is obfuscation.

Comment: Yes, but the whole connection is usually encrypted, so it's safe.

Comment: I checked on reputed sites with https and their login credentials and password are also visible on browsers HTTP headers.but u can check bank websites which showing password in encrypted form in HTTP headers.I just want like that on my magento store

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this.

Usually attacks on web-sessions include active / man-in-the-middle attacks. That means that even if you send a secret or public key to the JavaScript in the browser that that key may be replaced by an attacker. So the best thing you can achieve in JavaScript is obfuscation.

What's missing is a trust framework (for now anyway, there are several crypto API's under development). As the certificates of the browser are not available to JavaScript, there is no good method to establish trust with the webserver. So in the end you cannot authenticate the other party.

This is why TLS is a strict requirement for any browser based security; TLS can make use of the certificates stored with the web-browser and it is therefore possible to know which server you are communicating with. The encryption and authentication of the data within TLS allows the password to be send in plain at the HTTP level in HTTPS.

Comment: Well, *almost* any browser based security.